# ViewController deinit after performing segue using Notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I'm basically receiving a remote notification and I want to redirect my user to the correct VC as soon as he clicks the notification.

I'm doing it using NSNotificationCenter to perform a segue from my rootVC, leading the user to the correct VC.

> NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:
>   "chooseCorrectVC:", name:chatNotificationKey, object: nil)

Since the observer was previously loaded, my **chooseCorrectVC** function is called first, so this is my "Init/Deinit" Log. I consider Init whenever viewDidLoad() is called.

> rootVC INIT
>
> SecondVC DEINIT
>
> rootVC DEINIT

```
func chooseCorrectVC(notification:NSNotification){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chatSegue", sender: notification)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

The issue is: the VC that is called with **chatSegue** does not get initialized and goes straight to deinit. I'm not sure why it's happening, maybe I'm not removing the observer correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are receiving the remote notification, I suggest you to just handle the notification at AppDelegate.swift at method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){

// Here you can define view controller and manage it.
   println("Received: \(userInfo)") 
// Make root view controller first as per your need as HomeViewController in following
                let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                var mainTabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
                var notificationNavController : UINavigationController = mainTabBarController.viewControllers?.first as! UINavigationController
                var homeViewController : HomeViewController = notificationNavController.viewControllers.first as! HomeViewController
                homeViewController.isNotified = true
                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTabBarController)
                self.window!.rootViewController = nav
                nav.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() 
}
```

You can manage another view controller to be push on viewdidload of homeviewcontroller via setting flag here. On view did load

```
if isNotified == true {
      // Push another view controller
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it for my firstVC (which is a VC embed in a Navigation View Controller). How would you perform a segue to the secondVC? 
This is how I'm doing it.
let navigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
            if let window = window{
                window.rootViewController = navigationController @Arvind

Comment: I have edited answer for your custom problem. I suggest not to use notification centre in that situation. you can share code with me to more review your problem.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot Arvind. I'm still wondering why it didn't work with the Notification. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure before review your code, but there is chances to execute notification observer in incorrect sequence and after setting up rootviewcontroller. May that is working when you debugging with breakpoints.